# Euclidean domain in which the quotient and remainder are always unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain in which the quotient and remainder are always unique. Does it follow that the ring $R$ is either a field or a polynomial ring $F[X]$ for some field $F$?

Comment: What about $R = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Ted with what Euclidean function? With the standard $|n|$ there are often two solutions, because $|r|<|n|$ allows $r$ negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that characterization is correct, see M. A. Jodeit, Jr., [Uniqueness in the division algorithm,](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2315810) Amer. Math. Monthly 74 (1967), 835–836.